Colspan not working in SLDS lightning Salesforce LWC
paste the below code in w3 school HTML code. I want the same UI using SLDS lightning but the rowspan is not working as it works using plain HTML tags. I tried all possibilities but they were not fruitful.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Product Dimension</th>
    <th>Width</th>
    <th>Depth</th>
    <th>Height</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>39</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
</body>
</html>

LWC HTML:
 <template>
  <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered" aria-label="Example table of Opportunities with vertical borders">
    <thead>
      <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
        <th class="" scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate" rowspan="2" title="Product Dimension">Product Dimension</div>
        </th>
        <th class="" scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Width">Width</div>
        </th>
        <th class="" scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Depth">Depth</div>
        </th>
        <th class="" scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Height">Height</div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
        
        <td data-label="Width">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="27">27</div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Depth">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="31 1/8">31 1/8</div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Height">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="39">39</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </template>


rowspan isn't working, because you put it on the div instead of the td. However, you'll need to change more than just that. SLDS just isn't compatible with rowspan; the styles end up forcing the cells to align to the header:

If you copy the HTML directly into LWC, it would work as you expect.
